# If else ladder in handlebar

Tags: handlebars.js

Can we give if else ladder in handlebar ?

ie what I want is like

```
if(variable == 'yes' )
{

}
else if(variable == 'no')
{

}
else
{

}
```

When I searched what I found is, if statement in handlebar is like

```
{{#if variable }}


{{/if}}
```

So here we cant check for a particular value. How can than be done in handlebar

Answer (score 0):

Handlebars If else checks will only check to see if there is a value in the case of a string, so as long as your first string is truthy it will hit the if block, meaning its not null or undefined. If you are wanting a if else ladder (i would suggest using a switch) then you need to use a helper.

```
{{conditionChecker MyVariable}} 

Handlebars.registerHelper('conditionChecker', function (value) {
    var retVal = '';
    if(value === 'yes') {
        retVal =  '<div></div>';
    } else if (value === 'no') {
        retVal = '<p></p>'
    } else {
        retVal = '';
    }
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(retVal);
});
```

Also if it is yes/no on your checks you should have those as booleans.

Comment: How can I use a `switch` in handlebars?

Answer (score 0):

Handlebars now supports {{else if}} as of 3.0.0. Therefore, your code should now work.

```
{{#if (includes theme.fontStyle "Caption_1_Bold,Caption_2_Bold")}}
   <dfn>Rating</dfn>
   <strong>{{text}}</strong>
{{else if (eq theme.fontStyle "Caption_2")}}
   <dfn>Score</dfn>
   {{text}}
{{/if}}
```